# Domino Designer - Cannot change Web Preview Port

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus-notes

I'm using IBM Notes and Domino Designer version 9.0.1 and would like to change the web preview port. I do this using the Domino Designer preferences. However, the change I make (clicking "Apply" and "OK" is not saved) is not saved. I wish to change the port from 80 to 5000 but each time I reopen the Designer preferences I see that the Web preview port has 80 as it's value. Why is it not possible to make this change? IBM Notes is installed on a Citrix Personal Desktop although I don't know if that could have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This property is set using a notes.ini parameter. perhaps your problem is that you can't save information to notes.ini or that this file is restored in some way.

Try to set it manually in notes.ini and check if it's still there before you launch the designer.

HTTPPreviewPort=5000

There was an error in 8.5.3 where the change of the preview port didn't work but that is fixed in newer versions.